# Deploying WebContent folder from github as a WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration, web.xml

I downloaded the following project as a zip file from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I was hoping to use my IDE to build me a WAR file but gave up after encountering some netbeans related dependencies.

After I managed to compile it in eclipse and obtained a classes directory which I placed within the WEB-INF folder of WebContent.

The webContent folder looks like a an average WAR folder so I zipped up WebContent and renamed it to WebContent.war which I deployed into my tomcat 6 webapps directory.  I am using the same JRE as I compiled it within to run tomcat.

However it won't run.

Content of the web.xml (located in WEB-INF is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>fileupload</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description/>
        <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>info.sudr.file.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

I can see the following message in my tomcat error log:

> 28-Dec-2013 20:20:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
>   SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name UploadServlet

If I then remove the following from web.xml (or move it to below the definition containing the servlet class):

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can see the bear bones html of the index.html located in WebContent but I can't access the servlet itself.

Am I right to suspect the form action being called in the index.html may need some mapping in the web.xml file also as I do not see how upload can do anything:

```
 <form id="fileupload" action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I have tried changing action to action="UploadServlet" and action="/UploadServlet" but to no avail.
I have uploaded the WAR file [here](http://d-h.st/lfg)   (Just click the smaller download button in the middle!)

Comment: Please rephrase _but I get access the servlet._

Comment: Are you getting a 404? Your `<form>` `action` attribute should have the same value as is mapped in your `<servlet-mapping>` `<url-pattern>`

Comment: I get a 404 if I do not move the servlet mapping tag containing the url-pattern below the Servlet mapping with a UploadServlet display name tag. The corresponding message in tomcat logs is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name UploadServlet.

Comment: Move the `<servlet-mapping>` to under the `</servlet>` and try again with `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/upload"`. What do you see when submitting the form?

Comment: No joy, were you able to deploy it ?